# Python continue indentation in While loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, menu, continue

I am writing a program that has multiple options to modify a dictionary in python. The user has four options, and after completing an option I want the program to bring back the user to the main menu.
So far, every option works correctly except it doesn't bring the user back to the main menu, and instead loops for ever

```
user_input = int(input("Faites un choix..."))
liste_epicerie = {}
while True:

    if user_input == 1:
        print(liste_epicerie)
        if liste_epicerie == {}:
            print("La liste est vide")
            continue
```

So this code should bring back the user to user_input, but instead prints "La liste est vide" for ever.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well `True` is always true so yea it's going to loop forever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actually read the user input again (inside the loop):

```
liste_epicerie = {}

while True:
    user_input = int(input("Faites un choix..."))
    if user_input == 1:
        # ...
    elif ...:
        # ...
    # under some condition
    break
```

The variable `user_input` does not magically remember and repeat how its value came to be.

Answer (score -1):

```
sum=0
count=0
while True:
  n=input ("enter the value :")
  if n=="exit":
    break
    try:
     float(n)
    except:
     print ("enter the numeric value")
  continue
   sum=sum+n
   count=count+1
print(sum,count,sum/count)
```

Comment: Please add an explanation in text of why the shown code solves the OP's problem.